# Imported typescript class's instantiation does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was coding a NodeJS server-side using Typescript, when I came across this scenario. I created a class `Secret` to provide me with the environment variables set. Here is it.

```
import Logger from './logger';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as fs from 'fs';
class Secret {    

    private ENVIRONMENT: string;

    public constructor() {
        this.setEnvironmentVaribales();
    }

    private setEnvironmentVaribales(): void {
        if (fs.existsSync('.env')) {
            Logger.logError('Using .env file to supply config environment variables');
            dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
        } else {
            Logger.debug('Using .env.mm file to supply config environment variables');
            dotenv.config({ path: '.env.mm' }); 
        }
        this.ENVIRONMENT = process.env['NODE_ENV'];
    }

    public get environment(): string {
        return this.ENVIRONMENT;
    }
}

export default Secret;
```

I then imported the `Secret` to '`Logger` where I initialize my logger. Here is the code in `logger.ts`

```
import  * as Winston from 'winston';
import Secret from './secret';

class Logger {
    private logger: Winston.Logger;
    private secret: string;
    public constructor() {
        this.secret = new Secret().environment;
        console.log(this.secret);
        this.initializeLogger();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the winston logger
     */
    private initializeLogger(): void {
        this.logger = Winston.createLogger({
            transports: [
                new (Winston.transports.Console)({ 
                    level: Secret.ENVIRONMENT === 'production' ? 'error' : 'debug' 
                }),
                new (Winston.transports.File)({ 
                    filename: 'debug.log', 
                    level: 'debug'
                })
            ]
        });

        if (Secret.ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') {
            this.logger.debug('Logging initialized at debug level');
        }
    }
}

export default new Logger();
```

**The problem** is that Iam not getting the intended value in my `this.string`. Infact the new instance of `Secret` does not seem to be generating. Iam getting `undefined` as the result for the `environment` variable in `Logger`. 
Am I doing anything wrong here. 
**The only way it seems to work for me is when I change my `Secret` to export like this.**

```
import Logger from './logger';
import {dotenv} from 'dotenv/config';
import * as fs from 'fs';

if (fs.existsSync('.env')) {
   Logger.logError('Using .env file to supply config environment variables');
   dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
} else {
   Logger.debug('Using .env.mm file to supply config environment variables');
   dotenv.config({ path: '.env.mm' });  
}
export const ENVIRONMENT = process.env['NODE_ENV'];
```

*Or is it the circular dependency that is preventing it. `Logger` in `Secret` and `Secret` in `Logger`. If that is the case, I've even tried removing `Logger` import from `Secret` and used `console.log()`. But, still does not work the way I want it to be.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a circular dependency here:

- In `logger.ts`, the exported member is an instance of `Logger`: `export default new Logger()`
- In the constructor of the class `Logger`, the class `Secret` is instantiated: `new Secret().environment`
- In the constructor of the class `Secret`, the member `setEnvironmentVaribales()` is called, which uses the exported instance of `Logger` synchronously.

Your current solution is not valid too:

```
if (fs.existsSync('.env')) {
   Logger.logError('Using .env file to supply config environment variables');
   dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
} else {
   Logger.debug('Using .env.mm file to supply config environment variables');
   dotenv.config({ path: '.env.mm' });  
}
export const ENVIRONMENT = process.env['NODE_ENV'];
```

Here, `Logger` can't have the content of `ENVIRONMENT` before you export it.

## Solutions

The best solution is to NOT import the logger from `secret.ts`, because the Logger needs the content of this file to be completely executed first.

If you really need cross references, it'll work if your classes don't use each other from their constructors.

In any case, if the logger needs the secret before to do its job, you can't ask it to work before to give it that secret.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I knew this could be the only problem. But seems like I was testing it out with wrong command, after removing the `Logger` dependency from `Secret`. That's why I ended up getting the same old result. Thanks for your time.